# Keras prediction is hanging inside with graph.as_default() on Heroku

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, flask, keras

I have a Keras model loaded and making prediction inside a flask app. Locally it works fine, but on heroku it hangs indefinitely on `model.predict()` in below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = import_model()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
....

def predict_sentiment(X, tokens):

    for idx,_ in enumerate(tokens):

        token = tokens[idx][0]
        x_input = X[idx]

        global graph
        with graph.as_default():
            yhat = model.predict([[x_input]], verbose=0) # <--- HANGS
        ...
```

Originally I was running into the error, `Tensor Tensor(...) is not an element of this graph.` because each request thread was creating a new tensorflow session.

So I fixed with `keras.backend.clear_session()` but it was too slow to recreate the session on each request.

Then I found my current solution from [this post](https://kobkrit.com/tensor-something-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph-error-in-keras-on-flask-web-server-4173a8fe15e1). Which is to create one global session and reference it on each request.

Locally this is fast and works. But on heroku it gets stuck on that line without throwing any errors and I'm not sure why.

**Also tried:**

Loading the model inside `with graph.as_default():`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

with graph.as_default():
    model = import_model()
```

I know the model exists because I can print the model in the same `with...` block.

```
print(model.layers[0].input)
```

`=> <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f829836f588>`.

And can also print information about layers.

`print(model.layers[0].input)`

`=> Tensor("dense_1_input:0", shape=(?, 75684), dtype=float32)`

But it won't predict.

Answer (score 0):

Keras 2.2.5 and tensorflow 1.14.0 together works fine to overcome this error